# Multiple Async Http Client Calls in Java is Thread Safe

Tags: thread-safety, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am working with Async Http Client in Java with this [example](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-asyncclient-4.0.x/httpasyncclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/nio/client/AsyncClientHttpExchangeFutureCallback.java) . I just want to know about the performance issues when we are calling multiple services at a time asynchronously . I am concerned about the number of CPU cores  and the number of threads used in this example. I want to know more about this like :

1. Is this example uses multiple threads for each request.
2. If suppose I am making n number of calls at that time CPU cores will not support this to run , how I come to know how many threads it will support based in CPU ?
3. Is this example is Thread Safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this example uses multiple threads for each request.

No, it does not

> how many threads it will support based in CPU

By default the underlying I/O reactor starts one I/O dispatch thread per CPU core

> Is this example is Thread Safe

This question is just too vague. Exactly what class instances are you talking about?

Thread-safety rules that apply to both blocking `HttpClient` and non-blocking `HttpAsyncClient` are

- clients are thread-safe
- connection managers are thread-safe
- request / response messages are not thread safe
- contexts are not thread safe

As far as `HttpAsyncClient` is concerned, as long as you do not use additional threads to process / generate content, `HttpAsyncClient` ensures proper access synchronization of all components involved.